# What is the meaning of :: in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

What is the exact meaning of :: ?
And apart from parent, what else are the different things we can use?

```
By.xpath("parent::*/parent::*")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### **The shortest answer I can manage**

`::` separates an axis name from a node test in an XPath expression.

### **The longer answer**

It does not make much sense to ask about the meaning of "`::` in Selenium", because it's not a feature of Selenium. It belongs to XPath, which is a W3C specification in its own right and is used to navigate XML or XHTML documents.

```
By.xpath("   parent::*/parent::*    ")
    ^                 ^             ^
Selenium            XPath        Selenium
```

Selenium just happens to embed XPath in their web application framework (which is a good thing!).

So, I've taken the liberty to answer the question: *What is the meaning of `::` in XPath?*

**The meaning of `::` in XPath**

In XPath, `::` does not mean anything on its own and only makes sense if there is

- a valid XPath axis identifier to the left
- a valid node test to the right

For example, `parent::*` is a valid XPath expression<sup>1</sup>. Here, `parent` is an XPath axis name, `*` is a node test<sup>2</sup> - and `::` marks the transition from the axis to the node test. Other possible axes are

```
ancestor              following-sibling
ancestor-or-self      namespace
attribute             parent
child                 preceding
descendant            preceding-sibling
descendant-or-self    self
following
```

Of course those are not just names, they have a very clear-cut semantic dimension: each of them defines a unique way to navigate an XML document (or, rather, a tree-like representation of such a document). Their meaning is straightforward in most cases, for instance, `following::` identifies something that "follows" the current context.

These tuples of axis and node test (or triples, also counting predicates) can be "chained together" with the binary `/` operator to form paths with several **steps**:

```
outermost-element/other/third
```

**Navigating a simple document**

```
<root>
    <person>James Clark</person>
    <person>Steve DeRose</person>
</root>
```

Naturally, navigation might depend very much on your current whereabouts. There are both absolute and relative path expressions. An example for an absolute path expression is

```
/child::root/child::person      | abbreviated syntax:     /root/person
```

As you can see, there is a `/` at the beginning of an absolute path expression. It stands for the document node (the outermost node of a tree, which is different from the outermost element node of a a tree). Relative path expressions look like

```
child::person                   | abbreviated syntax:     person
```

The relative path expression will only find the `person` element node if the current **context** is the `root` element node. Otherwise, it will fail to locate anything.

**Your XPath expression**

To sum up and use what we have learned so far:

```
By.xpath("parent::*/parent::*")
```

finds the element node that is the grandparent of the current node. The names of both the parent and the grandparent node do not matter (that's what `*`is for). There's no `/` at the beginning, so it must be a relative path.

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, it is a *location path*, a special kind of XPath expression. Also, I have left out one important concept: *predicates*. Good things always come in threes, and XPath expressions come with an axis, a node test and with zero or more predicates.

<sup>2</sup> A node test must be either a *name test* (testing the name of a node) or a *kind test* (testing the kind of node). Find ample information about node tests in the [relevant part of the XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests).

Answer (score 1):

This is xpath syntax, you can do other things like :

```
child::*            Selects all element children of  current node
attribute::*        Selects all attributes of  current node
child::text()   Selects all text node children of  current node
child::node()   Selects all children of current node
```

Check a tutorial, especially about axes :

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp

Comment: Awesome answers by Mathias and Gerard. Thanks a lot guys